# Evaluate many boolean expressions like Array#join in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar, boolean-expression

In Ruby, you can use [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) to simple join together multiple strings with an optional delimiter.

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

I'm wondering if there is nice syntactic sugar to do something similar with a bunch of boolean expressions.  For example, I need to `&&` a bunch of expressions together.  However, which expressions will be used is determined by user input.  So instead of doing a bunch of

```
cumulative_value &&= expression[:a] if user[:input][:a]
```

I want to collect all the expressions first based on the input, then `&&` them all together in one fell swoop.  Something like:

```
be1 = x > y
be2 = Proc.new {|string, regex| string =~ regex}
be3 = z < 5 && my_object.is_valid?
[be1,be2.call("abc",/*bc/),be3].eval_join(&&)
```

Is there any such device in Ruby by default?  I just want some syntatic sugar to make the code cleaner if possible.

Comment: Do you want each part to take arguments and dynamically change, or are they previously determined? For example `be1` does not make sense unless `x` and `y` are already given, in which case it will be a constant of either `true` or `false`, but `be2` is a proc, which always evaluates to a truethy value, which is also a constant, and would not make much sense unless you are going to apply that to some arguments. It seems you are mixing these.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try [`Array#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F). If `arr` is an Array of booleans, this works by itself:

```
arr.all?
```

will return `true` if every element in `arr` is true, or `false` otherwise.

You can use [`Array#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) in the same manner for joining the array on `||`, that is, it returns `true` if any element in the array is true and `false` otherwise.

This will also work if `arr` is an array of `Procs`, as long as you make sure to pass the correct variables to `Proc#call` in the block (or use class, instance, or global variables).

Answer (score 20):

You can use `#all?`, `#any?` and `#none?` to achieve this:

```
[true, false].any?
=> true

[true, false].all?
=> false
```

And don't forget, that all values other than `nul` and `false` evaluate to `true`.

```
['', [], {}].all?
=> true
```

Comment: That's amazing! Really nice to know it.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you just want to filter your expressions hash by those which the user has selected, and then test if all those expressions are truthy:

```
cumulative_value = expression.select {|k, v| user[:input][k] }.values.all?
```

This will first select all members from expression for which there is a matching `user[:input]` key, then it will use `Array#all?` to test if all the values from the selected expressions are truthy. Your `cumulative_value` is then either true or false.

Since your expression values may be procs, you would then have to evaluate all procs from the filtered expression list, and build a results array from that, which you can call `all?` on:

```
cumulative_value = expression.select {|k, v| user[:input][k] }.
  values.map {|value| value.is_a?(Proc) ? value.call : value }.all?
```

Hardly "syntactic sugar", but it gets the job done without being horribly complex.